# NodeJS Unhandled rejection error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, angular-promise

I've been recently envolved in a nodejs project and while trying to use promises between my database accesses and my routing I encountered the error **Can't set headers after they are sent** when asking for a response at http://localhost:8080/api/user . Although I'm aware of many solutions at stack none worked out for me so here is my routing code at **router.js**

```
 server.get('/api/user/', function (req, res) {

        database.getUser()
            .then(function(data){
                res.send(data);
            }, function(err){

                res.send(500,{error: err});
            });

    });
```

And the first part of **database.js** including the function **getUser**

```
(function() {

'use strict';
var Promise = require('bluebird'), 
    mysql = require("mysql"),
    bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'),
    client;

exports.connect = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        client = mysql.createPool({
                connectionLimit : 100,
                waitForConnection: true,
                host     : 'localhost',
                user     : 'root',
                password : 'root',
                database : 'public',
                debug    :  false
            });
            if(!client){
                reject('Deu merda');
            }
            else{
                resolve();
            }
    });
}


exports.getUser = function(){
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
     var query = "SELECT name FROM public.users";
     query = mysql.format(query);
     client.query(query,function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });   
     });
}
```

Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

EDIT: I was checking my code again and I have a middleware to check if a user has permission to access a certain page, since it is one of the last options remaining where I could be changing something here it is:

```
 (function() {

    'use strict';

    var routes = require("./routes"),
        cookie = require("./utils");

    module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

        var i;

        if (req.url.split('/')[1] == 'api') {

            // START REGION: API permissions (all)
            for (i = 0; i < routes.api.all.length; i++) {
                if (routes.api.all[i].indexOf(req.url) > -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i != routes.api.all.length) {
                next();
            } else {

                // END REGION: API permissions (all)

                // START REGION: API permissions (logged)
               cookie.verifySession(req.cookies.session)
                    .then(function (userId) {

                        for (i = 0; i < routes.api.logged.length; i++) {
                            if (req.url.indexOf(routes.api.logged[i]) > -1) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (i == routes.api.logged.length) {
                            return res.sendStatus(403);
                        } else {
                            next();
                        }

                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        return res.sendStatus(403);
                    });

            }

            // END REGION: API permissions (logged)

        } else {

            // START REGION: Views permissions (all)

            cookie.verifySession(req.cookies.session)
                .catch(function (err) {
                    if (res.statusCode == null) {
                        return res.redirect('/forbidden');
                    }
                });

            for (i = 0; i < routes.views.all.length; i++) {
                if (routes.views.all[i].indexOf(req.url) > -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (i != routes.views.all.length) {
                next();
            } else {

                // END REGION: Views permissions (all)

                // START REGION: Views permissions (logged)

                cookie.verifySession(req.cookies.session)
                    .then(function (userId) {

                        for (i = 0; i < routes.views.logged.length; i++) {
                            if (req.url.indexOf(routes.views.logged[i]) > -1) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (i == routes.views.logged.length) {
                            if (res.statusCode == null) {
                                return res.redirect('/forbidden');
                            }
                        } else {
                            next();
                        }

                    });

            }

            // END REGION: Views permissions (logged)

        }
        next();
}
}());
```

I have an auxiliary file where I add the permitions:

```
  {
    "api":{
        "all": [
            "/api/authenticate",
            "/api/user"
        ],

        "logged": [
            "/api/lessons"
        ],

        "admin": [

        ]
    },

    "views":{
        "all": [
            "/",
            "/user_management"
        ],
        "logged": [],
        "admin": [],
        "advanced": []


    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere you're trying to modify a header after content has been sent to the browser. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be in the posted code.

Comment: Any ideas where I should be looking for the error? I've tried a little bit of everything to be honest but I can't seem to find the trap I've fallen into.

Comment: It looks to me like your middleware can call `next()` more than once.  You may want to return after you call `next()` so none of those paths will hit the last `next()` at the end of your function.

Comment: I don't think that would happen in this particular case since, I think, we would only go through the first for + if and leave, don't you think so?

Comment: You're calling `next()` at the end of the middleware function.  So, any code path that hasn't hit a return before that will hit that `next()`.  But some other code paths also have their own calls to `next()`.  That's a double call.  Basically, your middleware isn't accounting for its async operations properly and doesn't have unique logic paths that only lead to calling `next()` or `res.redirect()` only once per request.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I wasn't thinking about those situations, it worked!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll make my comment into an answer since this answered your question:

It looks to me like your middleware can call `next()` more than once.

You're calling `next()` at the end of the middleware function.  So, any code path that hasn't hit a return before that will hit that `next()`.  But some other code paths also have their own calls to `next()`.  That's a double call.  Basically, your middleware isn't accounting for its async operations properly and doesn't have unique logic paths that only lead to calling `next()` or `res.redirect()` only once per request.

Comment: I had a similar issue: I was checking the validation results of express-Validator within a then(), redirecting if there were errors but my success redirect was outside of the then() and not part of the Promise. Thus both were executed and I was getting the 'Cant set headers after sent' error. Your answer made my day.